# Using \label in \footcite

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, labels, footcite

I am using footnotes for my citations

```
Some Text.\footcite[Specific Location in Text]{bibKey}
```

This works perfectly. However I am having problems referencing one of these footnotes in another footnote, e.g:

```
Some Text.\footcite[Specific Location in Text\label{label}]{bibKey}
Some other Text.\footnote{See footnote \ref{label}}
```

This does work and inputs the correct footnote number.
However it produces these errors:

```
Argument of \blx@range@aux@i has an extra }.

<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.46 ...bibkey}
                                                  
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

 file.tex, line 46
Runaway argument?

\blx@normrange@i {\write \@auxout {\string \newlabel {MYLABEL}{{\@currentlabel \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \blx@range@aux@i was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.46 ...bibkey}
                                                  
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

 file.tex, line 46
Runaway argument?

\blx@normrange@i {\write \@auxout {\string \newlabel {MLABEL}{{\@currentlabel \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \blx@range@aux@i.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.46 ...bibkey}^^M
                                                  
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.
```

Any idea how I can fix these errors?
Alternativly, is there another way to reference a footnote in another footnote?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The postnote format does some things to the text to be able to detect page ranges and add "p."/"pp." as appropriate. In particular the text may be expanded during processing. Here it helps to `\protect` the `\label`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authortitle, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite[Specific Location in Text\protect\label{label}]{sigfridsson}

Ipsum.\footnote{See footnote~\ref{label}}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: See footnote 1]

---

Depending on what exactly you need the linking for, there may be more elegant alternatives. The `verbose-note` styles (`verbose-note`, `verbose-inote`) for example automatically refer back to footnote with the first citation of a work.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=verbose-note, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite{sigfridsson}

Ipsum.\autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson and Ryde, see n. 1.]

It is be possible to transplant the `seenote` code to other styles and make use of the label that is set for the full citation for other purposes as well - it all depends on what exactly you need to do.

Comment: Using \protected fixed the errors. The second alternative is also useful. Thanks!