# Better way to repeat the same reference to a group of citation created with \footfullcite?

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, citing, footnotes, multiple-citations

I use `\footfullcite{ref1,ref2}` from the `biblatex` package to obtain a *single footnote* for *multiple citations* and I need to reference to that same footnote later in the document.

My current hacky way of doing this is the following

```
\footfullcite[\hspace{-.22em}\protect\label{refgroup}][]{ref1,ref2}
```

the use of `\protect` is fundamental, as I learnt [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549186/using-label-in-footcite) and when I want to add a second reference to the same footnote I use `\footref{refgroup}` (using the KOMA script functionality as explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74668/18204)).

As you can see, I need to manually add some negative horizontal space, because putting the label in the the `<prenote>` field of `\footfullcite` adds an some empty space (putting it in the `<postnote>` field ends the footnote with a comma instead of a full stop, so it's even worse).

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to achieve the same goal more elegantly?
[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71526/repeat-the-same-reference-in-footnote-on-different-pages) poses a similar problem, but the code suggested there does not show multiple citations in the *same footnote*.

Comment: Untested, but `\AtNextCite` may work for that label.

Comment: About why the use of the postnote there is a problem, you can see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/593907/105447

Comment: Thanks for the input! Using `\AtNextCite{\label{refgroup}}\footfullcite{ref1,ref2}`does not work as intended, but maybe you had in mind something different.

Comment: I have just realized that I can simply use `fullcite` and create the footnote manually, i.e. `\footnote{\fullcite{ref1,ref2}.\label{refgroup}}`. I guess I'll just create a macro for this.

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind. I believe whether it works or not depends on grouping. It was worth the shot.  :-)  But it was my best bet there. And about making your own footnote, the equivalent of `\footcite` would be `\footnote{\cite{ref1,ref2}}` I believe.